# Error Installing flipMaxDiff package from github

Tags: r, github, error-handling, install.packages

Relative newby here struggling with an older install for R. Trying to get flipMaxDiff from either of the remaining github repositories (Displayr doesn't provide anymore I guess). When I try either one through the "install_github" function, I get the following error:

**Error: object ‘TrimWhitespace’ is not exported by 'namespace:flipFormat'
Execution halted**

I tried loading flipFormat and TrimWhitespace separately to see if that would facilitate an error-free download but to no avail. If anyone has a thought on how I could get this puppy to work, I'd appreciate your expertise and insight.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I Implemented the changes suggested by user14831771 and some others to fix the errors while installing the package. You can install the package from the fork with the next lines

library(devtools)

install_github(pelishk/flipMaxDiff)

Answer (score 0):

How I hacked it: create a project in rstudio from version control->git flipMaxDiff.

Edit DESCRIPTION file in project root, Add "flipU," as a new line in the import section, and save.
Edit the data.R in R folder. On line 67 change
`"#' @importFrom flipFormat TrimWhitespace`
to
`#' @importFrom flipU TrimWhitespace` and Save.
Build->Build binary package
Build->Install and restart